# Переменная JAVASCRIPT в переменной PHP

Tags: javascript, php, html

можно ли как-то связать JS и PHP, чтобы в переменной PHP указывалась переменная JS

что я наклянчил:

```
<script>
$("button").on('click', function() {
  var moderate = $("#moderate option:selected").val();
  if(moderate != 'Статус') {
    location.href = "https://site.ru/admin?moderate="+ moderate;
  }
  return false;
});
<?php
$moderate = КАК УКАЗАТЬ СЮДА VAR MODERATE???
?>
</script>
```

Comment: передайте значение через ajax

Comment: можете пожалуйста, показать пример? а то я начинающий ;(

Comment: если покажите, как сделать это по моему примеру, буду очень благодарен 

Comment: ровно миллиард примеров можно найти и на этом сайте и в гугеле вбив соответствующий запрос.

Answer (score 0):

```html
<script>
    $("button").on('click', function() {
      var moderate = $("#moderate option:selected").val();
      if(moderate != 'Статус') {
        location.href = "https://site.ru/admin?moderate="+ moderate;
      }
      return false;
    });
    <?php
        $moderate = htmlspecialchars($_GET['moderate']);
    ?>
</script>
```

Comment: огромное спасибо!!!! :)